# Ajax request and jquery conflict

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have gallery.php that loads images with src path from a database.
I also have an external main.js that detects a click on a `.thumbnail`.

Everything works flawlessly until I load different images (another category of images, another set) via ajax.  (the `load()` function of jquery) Everything shows just fine, but a problem with javascript appears.

After that, I can't retrieve the `src` attribute of my thumbnail. Here's what I mean.

**BEFORE AJAX**

Category 1 pictures/thumbnails

```
<a class="thumbnail"><img src="ressources/images/image1Small.jpg" /></a>';
<a class="thumbnail"><img src="ressources/images/image2Small.jpg" /></a>';
<a class="thumbnail"><img src="ressources/images/image3Small.jpg" /></a>';
```

And so on...

**AFTER AJAX CALL**

Category 2 pictures/thumbnails

```
<a class="thumbnail"><img src="ressources/images/image4Small.jpg" /></a>';
<a class="thumbnail"><img src="ressources/images/image5Small.jpg" /></a>';
<a class="thumbnail"><img src="ressources/images/image6Small.jpg" /></a>';
```

As you can see, everything is like before. The a tag has the same class as the old est of pictures. But when I call the function containing :

```
var path = $(this).children().attr("src");
```

It now returns : `undefined` instead of `ressources/images/imageXSmall.jpg`

I tried checking if `$(this)` returned something else after, but no success.

I was wondering if when an external .php file was loaded via jquery.load(), the link between those newly created `<a class="thumbnail">` tags and `main.js` were lost. Like if I had to reload `main.js` after the `jquery.load()` function. Or something like that...

Thank you!

**EDIT** Here's the code:

- When clicking on a link to different
  category
  *.linkSubCat being different categories*

  $(".linkSubCat").click(function(){loadImages($(this).attr("id"));});

*then*

```
function loadImages(pCategory) {
    switch (pCategory) {
        case "subCat00":
            $(".pics").load('loadImages.php',{category:0});
            break;
        case "subCat01":
            $(".pics").load('loadImages.php',{category:1});
            break;
        case "subCat02":
            $(".pics").load('loadImages.php',{category:2});
            break;
        case "subCat03":
            $(".pics").load('loadImages.php',{category:3});
            break;
        default:
            $(".pics").load('loadImages.php',{category:0});
            break;
    }
}
```

*loadImages.php*

```
<?php
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root", "") or die("Error Connecting : " . mysql_error());

    if (!mysql_select_db("taktak")) die('Error connecting to database : ' . mysql_error());

    function createThumbPHP() {
        if(isset($_POST['category'])) {
            if($_POST['category'] == 0){
                $imageQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_pictures WHERE p_category = 0");
                $thumbHtml = '';

                while ($tempImageQueryFetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($imageQuery)){
                    $thumbHtml .= '<a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="ressources/images/' . $tempImageQueryFetch["p_fileName"] . 'Small.jpg" /></a>';
                }
            }elseif($_POST['category'] == 1){
                $imageQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_pictures WHERE p_category = 1");
                $thumbHtml = '';

                while ($tempImageQueryFetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($imageQuery)){
                    $thumbHtml .= '<a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="ressources/images/' . $tempImageQueryFetch["p_fileName"] . 'Small.jpg" /></a>';
                }
            }elseif($_POST['category'] == 2){
                $imageQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_pictures WHERE p_category = 2");
                $thumbHtml = '';

                while ($tempImageQueryFetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($imageQuery)){
                    $thumbHtml .= '<a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="ressources/images/' . $tempImageQueryFetch["p_fileName"] . 'Small.jpg" /></a>';
                }
            }elseif($_POST['category'] == 3){
                $imageQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_pictures WHERE p_category = 3");
                $thumbHtml = '';

                while ($tempImageQueryFetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($imageQuery)){
                    $thumbHtml .= '<a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="ressources/images/' . $tempImageQueryFetch["p_fileName"] . 'Small.jpg" /></a>';
                }
            }
        return $thumbHtml;
        }
        else {
            $errorMSG = "Error Loading Images";
            return $errorMSG;
        }
    }

    echo createThumbPHP();
?>
```

So everything does what it's supposed to do. Here'sthe problem. This javascript code in main.js :

```
$(".thumbnail").click(
            function(){
                $('#imageBig img').remove();

                var path = $(this).children().attr("src");
                var newPath = path.substring(0, path.length-9);
                var newPath2 = newPath += ".jpg";

                var imageLoad = new Image();

                $(imageLoad).load(function () {
                    if (--imageLoad == 0) {
                        // ALL DONE!
                    }
                    // anything in this function will execute after the image loads
                    $('#loader').hide();
                    var newImg = $('<img />').attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
                    $('#imageBig').append( $(newImg) ); // I assume this is the code you wanted to execute
                })
                .attr('src',newPath2);
            }
        )
```

It removes the img in #imageBig, but doesn't seem to get the path of `$(this).children().attr("src");` This script worked perfectly before I loaded different thumbnails (even with the same setup (classes, order, ...))

Comment: Without seeing the code/demo it is hard to tell what is the problem

Comment: There you go. I gave you the code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [jQuery "live"](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event binding, eg

instead of this

> $(".thumbnail").click(

use this

```
$('.thumbnail').live('click',
```

---

When using the regular event binders (eg `$.click()`), the handler is only bound to those elements matched at the time of the call. When you load new elements via AJAX, these will not be bound.

From the jQuery manual

> Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.

Comment: Wow, It worked perfectly. Thank you, magician. You just saved me a lot of trouble.